# array of pointer to functions c++

Tags: c++

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code?!
visual studio tells the operand of * must be a pointer...
(in line that we call operation)...
can someone tell how exactly declaring an array of pointer to functions is?
I'm really confused.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;


int power(int x)
{
  return(x*x);
}

int factorial(int x)
{
    int fact=1;
    while(x!=0)
    fact*=x--;
    return fact;
}

int multiply(int x)
{
    return(x*2);
}

int log(int x)
{
    int result=1;
    while(x/2)
    result++;
    return result;
}

//The global array of pointer to functions
int(*choice_array[])(int)={power,factorial,multiply,log};

int operation(int x,int(*functocall)(int))
{
    int res;
    res=(*functocall)(x);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int choice,number;
    cout<<"Please enter your choice : ";
    cin>>choice;
    cout<<"\nPlease enter your number : ";
    cin>>number;
    cout<<"\nThe result is :"<<operation(number,(*choice_array[choice](number)));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This call

```
operation(number, (*choice_array[choice](number)))
```

is invalid.

You have to supply a pointer to a function as second argument. Either write

```
operation(number, choice_array[choice] )
```

or

```
operation(number, *choice_array[choice] )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `(*choice_array[choice](number))` isn't a function itself but a result of function call.
Did you mean `(*choice_array[choice])`?

Comment: Yes, agree. But removing `(number)` was the smallest change required to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

operation takes a function as argument, but `(*choice_array[choice](number))` is an int, cuz it's applying `choice-array[choice]` to `number`

just do `operation(number, choice_array[choice])`

EDIT : don't want to say something wrong, but it seems to me that

```
*(choice_array[choice])

(choice_array[choice])
```

are the same, (meaning pointer to the function IS (can be used as a call to) the function, and you cant "dereference" it)